# Sorting Through a Complex Array of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spotify

**UPDATED**

I am using the Spotify api to get information about related artists based on artists that a user follows on my website.  I was wondering, how can I sort through the response I'm getting in order to display things a certain way.

For each artist followed on my site, I would like to sort the response of related artists by followers total from greatest to lowest.  If a user on my site follows more than 1 artist I would like the entire response of related artists info to be ordered by followers total.  For example if someone on my site follows Metallica and Oasis, I would like the related artists for both Metallica and Oasis to be ordered by followers total.  Right now my code only works correctly the way I want it to if a user is only following one artist.

How would I go about doing this?  I also don't want to have any duplicate artists in my response, because sometimes certain artists will have the same related artists.

Response I get for related artists when following 2 artists on my site (Metallica and Oasis).  Had to put it in a gist cause the response was to big to post here.

https://gist.github.com/jlquaccia/07998975d3f11324ab0d

Controller - users_controller.rb:

```
   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @hash_version_array = []

    @user.follows.each do |follow|
      response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/#{follow.artist_id}/related-artists")
      @hash_version = JSON.parse(response.body)
      @artist_name = follow.artist_name

      @hash_version_array << @hash_version
    end

    sorted = @hash_version_array.first["artists"].sort_by { |a| a["followers"]["total"] }
    @most_to_least_followers_version_array = sorted.reverse
  end
```

View - users/show.html.erb:

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h3>Recommendations</h3>
      <% if current_user.follows.count == 0 %>
        <p>Recommendations based on who you follow will appear here..</p>
      <% else %>
        <p>Based on your follows you might also like..</p>
        <% @most_to_least_followers_version_array.each do |item| %>
          <div class="artist_recommendation_wrapper">
            <div class="artist_recommendation artist_name newsfeed_artist">
              <%= item['name'] %>
            </div>
            <%= number_with_delimiter(item['followers']['total'], delimiter: ',') %> followers
            <%= link_to(image_tag(item['images'][0]['url'], class: 'img-responsive artist_recommendation_img', width: 200, height: 200), artists_path) rescue image_tag("microphone.png", class: 'img-responsive artist_img mic_bg', width: 200, height: 200) %>
            <br>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the hash you have this will do the job:

```
hash.first["artists"].sort { |a| a["followers"]["total"] }
```

when `hash` contain the response JSON parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was able to get the first item in @hash_version_array to be ordered by Spotify followers total but if a user on my site follows more than one artist I would like things to be ordered for all sets of related artists.. how can I achieve this?  made edit above..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array that contains all the followed artists. Change this line:

```
  @hash_version_array << @hash_version
```

to

```
  @hash_version_array << @hash_version["artists"]
```

and sort with

```
@hash_version_array.sort { |a| a["followers"]["total"] }
```

As an aside: you don't need all those variables to be global (indicated by the '@'). That should be reserved for data you need in your template. It might also be a good idea to put stuff like this into the model, and possibly write the Spotify API responses to the database – that way you could use ActiveRecord with all its magic.

You should also try to abstract away as much information as possible when asking question here. I. e. it's not really relevant that the data came from the spotify API and you could have made your life and this question easier by working with a smaller dataset.